# Javascript Equal Probability

Tags: javascript, math

Hi I need a probability in javascript that is a function and returns X 1 in every 2 times and Y 1 in every 30.2 times. The rest of the time the function should returns Z.

The function should be able to be called many times in a row.

This is what I have came up with so far

```
probability(){
var randomNumber = random() * 100;
if (randomNumber > 50) {
   x()
}
else if (randomNumber > 3.31125827815 ) {
   y()
}
else {
   z()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your function will call `y()` if randomNumber is between 3.3 and 50. You probably want `<` instead of `>`

```
else if (randomNumber < 3.31125827815 ) {
```

---

It might make it a bit more readable to sort the intervals in ascending order:

```
function probability(){
    var r = random();
    if (r < 1/30.2){
        y();
    }else if(r < 0.5){
        z();
    }else{
        x();
    }
}
```